# add a lot of controls to a Composite

Tags: swt

I have to add a lot of controls to a composite (600+). This takes a lot of time. Is there a way to do this more efficiently ? Maybe suppress some events ?

I do the add dynamically, based on some user input (button click, checkbox check/uncheck, etc.)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling intermediate redraws:

```
parentComposite.setRedraw(false);
try {
  // perform all needed work
} finally {
  parentComposite.setRedraw(true);
}
```

This can speed up the time it takes to do ui work considerably in some cases.

Comment: Good idea. My dialog is now about 25% faster when adding items and about 65% faster when removing items. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My first hint would be to use a wizard to spread the controls throughout various screens.

Comment: I can't really do this. There is a command panel on the left and on the right site a preview panel that updates depending on the selection on the left. I can not have the user go back and forth between the two dialogs.